# to be drawn to someone

Tags: meaning

What does *being drawn to someone* mean in the case of a movie or book character?
(the complete question is: *to which character in the film were you the most drawn?*)

Comment: *drawn* simply means *attracted* in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means "which character was the most interesting to you?" or "which character did you relate to the most?"